# asp.net mvc exception in controller not beign handled at custom ErroHandler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I have a global ErrorHanlder (Derive from HandleErrorAttribute) that works fine and catches all errors that occur. But I have a situation in which, home controller can throw exception. I inspected and saw that error thrown from controller is  not handled in my custom ErrorHandler and asp.net gives this:

```
Exception of type 'Exception' was thrown.

An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Would you help me please ?

Code:

```
    public HomeController()
            {

                    _ServiceAsync = new ServiceAsyncProvider();

            }

class ServiceAsyncProvider
{
   public ServiceAsyncProvider()
     {
            throw new Exception(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the code that is throwing the exception as well as error handler?

Comment: @Jax Edited the question and provided it with code

Comment: Is `_ServiceAsync` instantiated in the constructor?

Comment: yes it is instantiated in Controller Constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code snippet is a little unclear on this point, it looks like your _ServiceAsync is being initialized in your controller's constructor. **Exceptions thrown during controller construction are not handled by the HandleError filter.**

See this related question for more information: [Handling Exceptions that happen in a asp.net MVC Controller Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694849/handling-exceptions-that-happen-in-a-asp-net-mvc-controller-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing an exception in the constructor. These exceptions are not handled by the filter.